# I am unable to link confirm box with paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html

If the user clicks OK on the confirm box he can visit the webste else he will be denied. How to pass on the innerHtml text into the paragraph tag?

```js
// Confirm Box
if(confirm("Please confirm that you are a citizen of India.") == true)
{ document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = "Welcome to our Website!";
}
else
{ document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = "Access Denied";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PromptBox, ConfirmBox, AlertBox</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The mistake you made was that you typed `b` instead of `B` in `document.getElementById("")`. Remember that javascript is a case-sensitive language.

```js
// Confirm Box
if(confirm("Please confirm that you are a citizen of India.") == true)
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Welcome to our Website!";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Access Denied";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PromptBox, ConfirmBox, AlertBox</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and came back to answer my own question. How did you even observe such a small detail. I should start using error console from firefox for such mistakes and then post it here I guess.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please up-vote and give me the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
(function() {
    if (confirm("Please confirm that you are a citizen of India.") == true) {
        document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = "Welcome to our 
        Website!";
    } else {
        document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = "Access Denied";
    }

})();
</script>
```